# Can you make a template from a step in Azure Logic app and use for all?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have 10~ Azure Logic apps that all share that they need to get a JWT-token before making a second HTTP-call. The authentication-step looks the same in all apps and use the same parameters. Right now I am copying the auth-step for every entry in the resource-step in the ARM-template.

I would like to make a shareable template of this step in order to make the ARM-template more readable and less repetitive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As your logic apps has same authentication steps and use the  same parameters, you can use Cookie to authenticate it.

In logic app you can create `Http` connector and click `Add new parameter` to choose `Cookie`. Then after first http-call, you can retrieve the cookie and send the cookie to second, third http-call and so on.

[image]

In code view you can see the template as below:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "cookie": "ARRAffinity=45235a969147eb4ab6bcxxxxxxxxx; AppServiceAuthSession=s3pEd3Kp9LHsCZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Http"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this article about [Call an API with cookie authentication from a Logic App](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/howto-call-an-api-with-cookie-authentication-from-a-logic-app/).